# Testosterone and bodyfat correlation -- a myth or no?

Tags: testosterone

I've heard people claim that steroids or just even higher natural test with make the body remove fat regardless of diet. I think this idea comes from those YouTube fitness guys who do massive calorie binges and have ripped bodies year round. It's claimed that they can eat anything they want and never gain an ounce of fat because they're on such high amounts of exogenous testosterone and other drugs. Is this true? The guys on gear can lower their bodyfat constantly while still building loads of muscle and eat like pigs all day and have perfect bodies?

Naturals can't seem to do this -- or at least the people who claim to be. I have spend a long time trying to up my test naturally in hopes that my bodyfat will keep decreasing in spite of eating a constant calorie surplus, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I raised my natty test from 435 to 830 over less than 2 years, but I don't seem to be losing fat any faster or building muscle any faster either. I feel a massive difference in libido and m

Common beliefs would have it that you just down 5 grams of trenbolone and clenbuterol and sit around all day and you'll be shredded with tons of muscle even if you worked out like twice a year only. Some natties murder themselves and reach six-pack ab bodyfat while looking like skeletons because they lose so much muscle when dipping under 10% bodyfat with no drugs and/or can't maintain it. Guys on gear seem to not only maintain but gain substantial muscle even while cutting.

How does this relate to testosterone? How can they eat so much and never get fat? Diet so much and never lose an oucne of muscle and even build some too?  Are drugs really that magical?

Comment: I don't have any scientific evidence but I have heard that most steriods increase metabolism to some degree because you know, hormones..

Answer (score 1):

Can't speak from experience but there are studies -- However I don't see a reason to post these.

**Are you just asking this to see if they'd work for you - or what's your plan?**

You do realize any weight you lose or muscle gained from "roids" *(working out or otherwise)* **you'd lose once you stop taking them**.

There are some *great* rebound effects you'll experience which include damaged or desensitized androgen receptors, lower levels of bound and free T-testosterone along with increased estrogen and progesterone levels.

There are also plenty of life-altering, permanent and lethal side effects *(yes, really)* that would stick with you.

---

> *If you're trying to add size - post your workout routine / diet etc. 
>   Myself and others would be glad to help you out. Free professional
>   advice helping you add mass seems like a no brainer.*

---

With the long term effects known -- unless you have a terminal illness where it has been proven to be beneficial (such as adding lean muscle mass in patients with HIV) -- there isn't a reason to even consider taking them.

### Here are a few side effect which are often permanent:

- Cancer
- Severe Acne
- Damage to the Gonads *(testicles or ovaries)*
- Liver Diseases
- Malfunctions of the Kidneys *(liver or heart)*
- 'Roid Rage', which is characterised by uncontrollable outbursts of
  psychotic aggression
- Paranoia
- Mood Swings
- Severe Depression

Comment: It feels like you are not really answering the question, you're just giving a lecture about the side effects of taking steriods. The question is about the correlation between higher test and lower bf percentages.

Comment: Sorry wasn't intended to come off that way just don't want people to see that steroids lowers bodyfat and increases muscle mass  -- with zero considerations of the life ending / changing consequences.  Yes -- to answer your question with or without (to a lesser degree) exercise you will add lean muscle mass.  Here is a link to one of the better studies showing this:   http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM199607043350101#t=articleResults

Comment: Yeah it's good that you show both sides nonetheless, I feel the same way, too many people only see the short-term effects that steriods give you.

Comment: @MJB true -- I find it's easy to fall into the "that will never happen to me" syndrome.  Which seems to be used as a common way to convince yourself to take them.